# how to assign same color to marker and marker border in px.scatter() plot?

Tags: python, plotly

Hi I am using below code from official website.

https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/

The marker border color is defined as same color which is 'DarkSlateGrey'. I am wondering if it is possible to make border color the same as marker color for different markers?
Thanks

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",color_discrete_sequence=['blue','red','green'])

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                              line=dict(width=2,
                                        color='DarkSlateGrey')),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another way to do it, but do you want to specify a color for each category in the graph object and loop through it? Or, you could directly rewrite the data used to create the graph. My answer is to update the data directly.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x="sepal_width",
                 y="sepal_length",
                 color="species",
                 color_discrete_sequence=['blue','red','green'])

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                              line=dict(
                                  width=2,
                                  color='DarkSlateGrey'
                              )),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))

for i,c in enumerate(['blue','red','green']):
    fig.data[i].marker.line.color=c
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I realized after answering that the easiest thing to do is to stop setting marker lines in the graph update. `#line=dict(width=2,color='DarkSlateGrey')`